# Limited wireless connection on Windows 8.1

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, windows-8.1, wireless-router

I have a PPPoE connection and I wanted to set up a router.

I have followed the steps (at least I think I have) - connected the cable to router (internet blue port) then another cable from router (yellow port) to PC and proceeded with a quick setup from `http://tplinklogin.net/`. I've entered my connection credentials, set up and SSID and a PW and I've received the message that che wireless connection has been established succesfully.

However, if I want to connect to the wireless connection from PC, the connection is Limited.
On the other hand, I can connect to it from my phone and works fine.

What other steps are needed to finish the setup succesfuly?

Could it be inappropriate Wireless drivers? I am using the ones installed by default by Windows 8.1.

Comment: 1. Open `Control Panel` 2. Open `Network and Sharing Center` 3. Click `Manage Network Adapters` at left 4. Right click your wifi adapter 5. Click `Diagnose`. This should go through and reset your wireless adapter and hopefully fix

Comment: When you are in `Network and Sharing Center`, does it show *Private network* under the network name?

Comment: @BigChris, thanks for the advice. I've tried that but with no luck. After more searched over the web, I believe to be a driver-related problem...

Comment: @CharlieRB, it says it's public. But unlike the others, it seems it's not identified. It's displayed as "Unidentified Network", Public Network | Access Type : No internet connection,  Connections : the SSID I provided

Comment: Try deleting your SSID profile on the computer and re-connecting to it

Comment: @BigChris It didn't work. I had the well-known Limited connection problem on Win 8.1. I've posted an answer with the solution I adopted.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and a lot of possible solutions tried... I recommend others to do these (in this order) :

1. Make sure setup for the connection using the router, is fine. Make sure you enter the correct credentials. (Setup was fine in my case as I wasn't able to connect using my PC, but was fine using my phone)
2. Try to connect with other device than the current one (if possible with a phone). If it connects, then it might be a driver-related problem. Update to latest drivers.
3. If installed drivers do not work, try to follow **[this link](http://www.kapilarya.com/the-default-gateway-is-not-available)**.

I will write down the steps briefly, in case the link gets broken :

1. Open up `Device Manager` (you can find it in control panel)
2. Select the Network Adapter device (in my case was Broadcom 802.11n Network Adapter) and click Properties.
3. Select Drivers tab, then click the `Update Driver...` button.
4. Select the `Browse my computer for driver software` option and then `Let me pick...` option.
5. Uncheck the `Show compatible hardware` check box. Then search for `Broadcom 801.11a Network Adapter` and select it. Click next.

Connect to a wireless network now.